# Was Gordon Walker based on Blade?

Tags: marvel, supernatural, character-similarity, blade

In season 2 of *Supernatural*, we meet hunter [Gordon Walker](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Gordon_Walker) who ends up fighting vampires. I began wondering if this character was influenced by the Marvel comic book character [Blade](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_(comics)), who also fights vampires, and the two vaguely resemble one another in outward physical appearance and build.

In season 3, Gordon Walker even became

> a vampire, like Blade who is part vampire.

**Have those involved with making the show commented as to whether Gordon was based on or influenced by Blade?**

[image]

Comment: @AncientSwordRage why wouldn't this be tagged [character-similarity]?

Comment: Just a mental calculation on the [tag calculation](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7871/3804) score puts it pretty low.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the producers did not base Gordon on Blade, but it is more like a nod to Marvel's character "Blade". Both are African-American vampire hunters (like you stated). And also, Gordon's last name "Walker" hints at Blade whom the vampires call "Daywalker" for his ability to walk in daylight (Blade is half vampire).
The producers did not give any special hints on this subject, but the fans are quite used to the different nods given : for example, in the Season 7 episode 23,

> Dean says to Meg : Shut up, Meg.

which is a clear nod to the series "Family Guy".